# How to locate oozie job id from one of its actions - application id?

Tags: oozie

I was given an oozie java action's application id (**Example**: *application_1174263307816_3337022*). Using this, how to retrieve the oozie job id and workflow name?

Comment: That's a YARN "application" ID. The first step would be to open the YARN ResourceManager UI and check the details about that app - or use the command-line interface i.e. `yarn application -status <id>`

Comment: Thanks for this useful info Samson